# Contact high: is it notable?

Tags: discussion, support

I asked a question regarding the phenomenon of "contact high", which is sometimes dismissed as psychological, and sometimes accepted as real, here: [Can you get high from second-hand marijuana smoke?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10692/contact-high-are-tiny-doses-of-secondhand-marijuana-measurably-psychoactive)

I found that second-hand marijuana exposure is known to affect drug-tests, and this is why a threshhold is set at 50ng per unit blood (whatever it was) for someone to have been considered actively smoking marijuana. I was asking to see if there are established psychoactive effects at concentrations of 4 ng, 1 ng, or even .1 ng. I am curious about the literature, I couldn't find the answer by googling.

I think this is obviously notable, and I think sklivvz just doesn't like me. Could someone reopen the question. If the question is badly phrased, I'm sorry. I feel kind of foggy today, as this question was inspired by unfortunate recent events.

Answer (score 4):

I will be happy to reopen your question once you provide proof of notability.

This is our policy. Surely, if it's "obviously" notable, it won't be hard to find people that claim so and link to them.

There's no need to come to meta and claim mods don't like you. Try to focus on your constructive side and please leave any personal accusation at home next time.

Comment: It's ok if you don't like me.